# Using MediatR in Web API - How do you handle different status codes

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr

I am using (and learning how to use) MediatR and am trying to use it in my Web API.  My question is, assuming that the goal of the 'controller' is to look like the following where you simply send off the message:

```
[ApiController]
public class List : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public List( IMediator mediator )
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet( "/calc-engines" )]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CalcEngine[]>> HandleAsync(
        [FromQuery] Query query,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default ) => await mediator.Send( query, cancellationToken );
```

What is the best practice to handle different status codes based on item not found, forbidden, etc.?

Do you have your handler return a complex type with a `Payload` (the requested item) along with an `HttpStatus` and then examine the result in the action and return appropriately?  Throw exceptions and catch in the action (or a filter) and set status based on exception type?

**Update**: This is the best I could come up with, but wondering if there is something better.

```
public class ApiResult<T>
{
    private ApiResult( HttpStatusCode failureStatus ) => FailureStatus = failureStatus;
    private ApiResult( T payload ) => Payload = payload;

    public T Payload { get; }
    public HttpStatusCode? FailureStatus { get; }
    public bool IsSuccess => FailureStatus == null;

    public static ApiResult<T> Fail( HttpStatusCode failureStatus ) => new ApiResult<T>( failureStatus );
    public static ApiResult<T> Success( T paylooad ) => new ApiResult<T>( paylooad );

    public static implicit operator bool( ApiResult<T> result ) => result.IsSuccess;
}
```

Then handler looks something like this:

```
public async Task<ApiResult<SomeType>> Handle( TRequest message, CancellationToken token )
{
    if ( badValidation )
    {
        return ApiResult<SomeType>.Fail( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
    }

    // do work...

    return ApiResult<SomeType>.Success( someResult );
}
```

And action looks something like this:

```
public async Task<ActionResult<ApiResult<SomeType>>> HandleAsync(
    [FromQuery] Query query,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
{
    var result = await mediator.Send( query, cancellationToken );

    if ( result ) return result;

    return StatusCode( (int)result.FailureStatus );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In the team I take part, we detach the controller/presentation layer from the Mediatr logic (which will be in our application/business layer).

As you did, we return a specified object `result` from the Mediatr commands/queries, stating success/unsuccess, holding the result payload or errors. However, we do not return HTTP status codes, since that is responsability of the controller - the controller handles the HTTP requests and responses, so only the controller needs to know the meaning of `Ok`, `Bad Request`, etc. In this way, we decouple the `presentation` and the `application` layers (we employ a [clean architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/modern-web-apps-azure/common-web-application-architectures#clean-architecture) scheme).

Thus, to map Meditr results in APIs, we often use two different strategies:

1. Middlewares to model responses. Example: if an input validation exception is thrown, a middleware catches it and retrieves a `Bad Request`;
2. Methods in the controllers to interpret responses. Examples: if a `Get endpoint` calls a `query` and the result payload is null, that is mapped to a `Not Found`; if a failed result is returned by the Mediatr, a `500` is returned.

`Pipeline behaviours` ([reference](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Behaviors)) may also be useful to you. They are classes that can be registered in the pipelines of commands/queries, executing in the specified order as middlewares. They are very useful, for example, to validate input conditions, handle exceptions, model responses, get metrics, etc. In your example, the following validation

```
if ( badValidation )
{
    return ApiResult<SomeType>.Fail( HttpStatusCode.BadRequest );
}
```

could go to a validation behaviour, for example, instead of staying inside the `Handle`. Here is a good [tutorial](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/mediatr-pipeline-behaviour/).

Answer (score 0):

My approach is pretty much as yours with some improvements and more useful methods overloads.
I am using a generic class named "DescriptiveResponse" which act almost like your "ApiResult":

```
public class DescriptiveResponse<T>
{

    public T Value { get; set; }

    public bool IsErrorState { get; set; }

    public string ErrorDescription { get; set; }

    public ErrorStatus ErrorStatus { get; set; }


    public static DescriptiveResponse<T> Success(T value)
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse<T>
        {
            Value = value
        };
    }

    public static DescriptiveResponse Error(ErrorStatus status)
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse
        {
            IsErrorState = true,
            ErrorStatus = status,
            ErrorDescription = status.ToString()
        };
    }

    public static DescriptiveResponse<T> Error(ErrorStatus status = ErrorStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse<T>
        {
            IsErrorState = true,
            ErrorStatus = status,
            ErrorDescription = status.ToString()
        };
    }

    public static DescriptiveResponse<T> Error(string customDescription, ErrorStatus metadata = ErrorStatus.CUSTOM)
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse<T>
        {
            IsErrorState = true,
            ErrorStatus = metadata,
            ErrorDescription = customDescription
        };
    }

    public static DescriptiveResponse<T> Error(T value, ErrorStatus status = ErrorStatus.UNEXPECTED_ERROR)
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse<T>
        {
            IsErrorState = true,
            ErrorStatus = status,
            ErrorDescription = status.ToString(),
            Value = value
        };
    }

    public DescriptiveResponse<TTarget> ToGeneric<TTarget>(TTarget newValue = default(TTarget))
    {
        return new DescriptiveResponse<TTarget>
        {
            Value = newValue,
            IsErrorState = this.IsErrorState,
            ErrorDescription = this.ErrorDescription,
            ErrorStatus = this.ErrorStatus
        };
    }

    public static implicit operator bool(DescriptiveResponse<T> response) => response.IsErrorState;
}
```

However, I use a list of custom error status which represented in form of "enum" named "ErrorStatus" that comes down to my needs:

```
public enum ErrorStatus
{
    CUSTOM = -1,
    UNEXPECTED_ERROR,
    NOT_FOUND,
    INPUT_IS_NULL,
    INPUT_INVALID,
    INTERNAL_ERROR,
    NO_ROWS_AFFECTED,
    UNAUTHORIZED,
    ALREADY_EXIST,
    AlREADY_INUSE
}
```

Then handler looks something like this:

```
public async Task<DescriptiveResponse<SomeType>> Handle( TRequest message, CancellationToken token )
{
    if ( badValidation )
    {
        return DescriptiveResponse<SomeType>.Error( errorDescriptionString, ErrorStatus.INPUT_INVALID );
    }

    // do work...

    return DescriptiveResponse<SomeType>.Success( someResult );
}
```

Finally, your 'controller' will looks like the following where you simply send off the message:

```
[ApiController]
public class List : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public List( IMediator mediator )
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    [HttpGet( "/calc-engines" )]
    public async Task<DescriptiveResponse<CalcEngine[]>> HandleAsync(
        [FromQuery] Query query,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = default ) => await mediator.Send( query, cancellationToken );
}
```

On the other hand, who want to consum you API should know about you status code list (the ErrorStatus enmu).

In this way, we decouple the presentation and the application layers where handlers prepare their response from business perspective with no needs to know the meaning of Ok or Bad Request.

Answer (score -1):

```
 public class ErrorHandler:Exception
{
    public HttpStatusCode Codigo { get; set; }
    public object Error { get; set; }

    public ErrorHandler(HttpStatusCode Code, object Err)
    {
        this.Codigo = Code;
        this.Error = Err;
    }
}
```

i work with mediatr and i handle exceptions with this code. usage example bellow

```
 var Comment = await contexto.TComentario.FindAsync(request.CommentId);
            
            if (Comment == null)
                throw new ManejadorErr.ErrorHandler(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound, new { Message = "comment no could be found" });
```